# Aggregate the json/struct column into an array

Tags: arrays, json, struct, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table as below:

| id | project |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name":"A", "status":x} |
| 1 | {"name":"B", "status":y} |

I want to aggregate them by id, so the result will be:

| id | project |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"name":"A", "status":x},{"name":"B", "status":y}] |

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out an easy one,

use the array_agg() function

```
select id, array_agg(project)
from table
group by id
```